# Why does my query return the same row multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to join two tables which share a common id, and it keeps returning a single row multiple times. Am working with codeigniter

This is the function from the model:

```
function get_latest_pheeds() {
    $data = $this->user_keywords($this->ion_auth->user_id);
    $keyword = $data;
    $user_id = $this->ion_auth->user_id;
    foreach($keyword as $key => $word) {
        $q = "SELECT *,COUNT(pheed_comments.comment_id) as comments
              FROM pheeds
              LEFT JOIN pheed_comments ON pheed_comments.P_id=pheeds.pheed_id
              WHERE pheed LIKE '%$word%' OR user_id='$user_id'
              ORDER BY datetime DESC";
        $result = $this->db->query($q);
        $rows[] = $result->result();
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Is my query wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` for your `COUNT()`

```
            $q = "SELECT *,COUNT(pheed_comments.comment_id) as comments
            FROM pheeds
            LEFT JOIN pheed_comments ON pheed_comments.P_id=pheeds.pheed_id
            WHERE pheed LIKE '%$word%' OR user_id='$user_id'
            GROUP BY pheed_id, pheed
            ORDER BY datetime DESC";
```

Now, since you are using `SELECT *`, there may be more columns returned with the `COUNT()`. For accurate results, you also must list them in the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY pheed_id, pheed, othercol1, othercol2, othercol3
```